# Plot benchmark's result in Go

Tags: go, benchmarking

Let's say I have written different functions to compute Fibonacci's nth number:

```
func fiboIterative(n int) {
   ...
}

func fiboRecursive(n int) {
   ...
}
```

And I'd like to get a chart showing the performances of each function depending on the value of n.

So far, I have been benchmarking using the built-in `testing` package which prints the time per operations to the console. Is there a simple way/package to run the benchmark for multiple values of n, stores the result in a csv or something similar and then plot them?

Comment: I've encountered the same issue in the past, as far as I know there isn't an easy way to do it. I ended up creating separate benchmark cases for representative values of n

Comment: thanks, I would have expected something like this to be built in... It is weird to provide a benchmarking utility without this

Comment: There is library that does it for you. Try out https://github.com/codingberg/benchgraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected something like this to be built in... It is weird to provide a benchmarking utility without this

It doesn't seem obvious to include a cross-platform plot library within the language packages, that will have to be maintained.

As it is now, you need to rely on third-party projects for a plot feature for benchmarks.

For example, the project **[`aybabtme/benchkit`](https://github.com/aybabtme/benchkit)** generates svg plot pictures from benchmarks.

> lightweight, feather touch, benchmarking kit. In comparison to the standard pprof utilities, this package is meant to help generating graphs and other artifacts.

[image: https://github.com/aybabtme/benchkit/blob/master/benchplot/tar_memplot.png]